# Type allowed keys of TypedDict

Tags: python, typeddict

I wonder how we should type a key, that corresponds to `TypedDict` instance.

Consider that there is a class, that accepts a dictionary as an input.
The dictionary is typed via `TypedDict`.
Let us say there is a method
that accesses the values of the dictionary by the key.
In this case the key must be a `Literal` containing allowed keys from the dictionary
as shown in the snippet below.

```py
from typing import Literal, TypedDict


class Data(TypedDict):
    one: str
    two: str


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data: Data) -> None:
        self.data = data

    def value(self, key: Literal['one', 'two']) -> str:
        return self.data[key]
```

But this solution is not convenient.
For example, if we extend `Data` by adding one more key, we will have to also add it into `key` type annotation.

Is there a programmable way to type `key`?

Comment: This seems like a very roundabout way to achieve a functionality akin to [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). Basically, you've a dictionary whose keys are strings but you want the keys to only be limited to a known set. Enums with attributes are discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12680080/839733).

Comment: Thanks, enums are really valuable. But we can get a dictionary from web api, for example, or from reading file as is. And we want to create a thin adapter between this raw data and the remaining parts of the system.

Comment: If you know the complete set of keys, obviously the code you've shown is good enough. If you don't know the complete set of keys, then no amount of typing will make this adapter work and the only type known is str. Again, this seems to be really bending over backwards for something trivial, but perhaps you've not disclosed your full intent, and there's more to the adapter than simply limiting the keys to a known set.

Comment: There is no way in the Python type system to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: _"we can get a dictionary from web api"_ ...[pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/) is commonly used for this use case, especially if you find yourself defining a wrapper class over the dict.

Comment: @Maxim Ivanov. Does this help?

    def value(self, _data: self.data, key: Literal['one', 'two'])-> Union[str, str]:
            return _data[key]

Comment: @Anentropic, thank you for the suggestion! But the question was mainly about static typing the potential key from the dictionary, not the runtime implementation.

Comment: @MaximIvanov in practice the Pydantic approach is better because it is futile to type-check external data without validating it, and also because it effectively combines the schema definition (your TypedDict) and the wrapper class into one thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question! The best way I can think of is using `Annotated` (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated)) this way:

```py
from typing import Annotated


def value(self, key: Annotated[str, Data.__required_keys__ | Data.__optional_keys__]) -> str:
        return self.data[key]
```

This is valid syntactically and semantically, but the type checkers do not know (yet) how to parse this properly, and will just skip the second part of the annotation as fallback.

Comment: It is not valid semantically, no part of the Python type hinting system supports this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Link to the doc added - this is definitely valid, even if not used yet by the type checkers as far as I know. Applications can make use of it (like FastApi does).

Comment: The question is about typing, though, and it is not a semantically valid type annotation