# Immutable enumeration in python using duck-punching

Tags: python

I am trying to create an enumeration in python. I have seen seen several solutions (The second answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python) by @alec thomas intrigued me most), but I would like to make the enumeration immutable. I found a [python recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413486-first-class-enums-in-python/) that is immutable, but I want to have a dict-like key/value association.

I was attempting to use duck-punching to add properties to the class that would throw an `AttributeError` if you tried to call `fset` or `fdel` on the property.

I ran into trouble defining the `fget` function of the property. Here's the code i have so far:

```
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    # Build property dict
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)

    # Define an errorhandler function
    def err_func(*args, **kwargs):
        raise AttributeError('Enumeration is immutable!')

    # Create a base type
    t = type('enum', (object,), {})

    # Add properties to class by duck-punching
    for attr, val in enums.iteritems():
        setattr(t, attr, property(lambda attr: enums[attr], err_func, err_func))

    # Return an instance of the new class
    return t()

e = enum('OK', 'CANCEL', 'QUIT')
print e
print e.OK
print e.CANCEL
print e.QUIT

# Immutable?
e.OK = 'ASDF'  # Does throw the correct exception
print e.OK
```

The output from this is:

```
<__main__.enum object at 0x01FC8F70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "enum.py", line 24, in <module>
    print e.OK
  File "enum.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    setattr(t, attr, property(lambda attr: enums[attr], err_func, err_func))
KeyError: <__main__.enum object at 0x01FC8F70>
```

Perhaps this is not the best way to create an enumeration, but it's short and I wanted to explore more of this whole duck-punching/monkey-patching concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that the `getter` of a `property` takes `self` as the only parameter, not `attr`. Therefore, you should use something like `lambda self: val` instead.

However, that doesn't work because the `lambda` binds the *name* `val`, which changes from iteration to iteration. So you will need to wrap it somehow:

```
def getter(val):
    return lambda self: val

for attr, val in enums.iteritems():
    setattr(t, attr, property(getter(val), err_func, err_func))
```

Comment: Thanks! The final solution looks like: `def getter(cls, val): return lambda cls: val`. The properties are inserted like this: `setattr(t, attr, property(getter(t, val), err_func, err_func))`

Answer (score 0):

The final implementation (thanks to @nneonneo).

- Checks for duplicate enum keys
- Checks if enum is empty
- Does not allow deletion or modification of enum items

  ```
  def enum(*sequential, **named):
      # Check for duplicate keys
      names = list(sequential)
      names.extend(named.keys())
      if len(set(names)) != len(names):
          raise KeyError('Cannot create enumeration with duplicate keys!')

      # Build property dict
      enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
      if not enums:
          raise KeyError('Cannot create empty enumeration')

      # Function to be called as fset/fdel
      def err_func(*args, **kwargs):
          raise AttributeError('Enumeration is immutable!')

      # function to be called as fget
      def getter(cls, val):
          return lambda cls: val

      # Create a base type
      t = type('enum', (object,), {})

      # Add properties to class by duck-punching
      for attr, val in enums.iteritems():
          setattr(t, attr, property(getter(t, val), err_func, err_func))

      # Return an instance of the new class
      return t()
  ```