# Pass enum to ndb.Model field in python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I find [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python) for how to create enum in python. I have a field in my `ndb.Model` that I want to accept one of my enum values. Do I simply set the field to `StringProperty`? My enum is

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

ALPHA = enum(A="A", B="B", C="C", D="D")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fully supported in the [ProtoRPC Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/) and it's not worth rolling your own.

A simple Enum would look like the following:

```
from protorpc import messages 

class Alpha(messages.Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 2
    D = 3
```

As it turns out, `ndb` has `msgprop` module for storing `protorpc` objects and this is [documented](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#msgprop).

So to store your `Alpha` enum, you'd do the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import msgprop

class Part(ndb.Model):
    alpha = msgprop.EnumProperty(Alpha, required=True)
    ...
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by [hadware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327143/hadware), a `msgprop.EnumProperty` is not indexed by default. If you want to perform queries over such properties you'd need to define the property as

```
    alpha = msgprop.EnumProperty(Alpha, required=True, indexed=True)
```

and then perform queries

```
ndb.query(Part.alpha == Alpha.B)
```

or use any value other than `Alpha.B`.

Comment: It is possible to query on the msgprop, and on the enum?

Comment: Have you tried to query on the `msgprop`? I'd guess it works just like an integer and you could use `ndb.query(Part.alpha == Alpha.B)`. You should start up a dev server and see for yourself.

Comment: I actually did it while asking the question, and yes it worked exactly as you suggested it, on one condition: **the `msgprop.EnumProperty(SomeEnumType)` had to be indexed** (and thus set this way: `msgprop.EnumProperty(SomeEnumType, indexed = True)`). You might want to add this to your answer to make it richer ;)

Comment: Good call. Thanks for checking.