# How to equate a string in python to a number

Tags: python

Folks I'm a newbie to python and I can't figure this out. I have a string that I want to equate to a number but I am at a loss. Here is code that I have so far but its not working. If there is an answer to my question please point me there.

Function takes an argument name and it should produce the corresponding number

```
    def name_to_number(name):
    name1 = "rock"
    name2 = "paper"
    name3 = "scissors"
    name4 = "lizard"
    name5 = "spock"

    name_rock = int(0, name1)
    name_paper = int(1, name2)
    name_scissors = int(2, name3)
    name_lizard = int(3, name4)
    name_spock = int(4, name5)

    if (name1 == "rock"):
        print name_rock
    elif (name2 == "paper"):
        print name_paper
    elif (name3 == "scissors"):
        print name_scissors
    elif (name4 == "lizard"):
          print name_lizard
    elif (name5 == "spock"):
        print name_spock
    else :
        print "None of the numbers match"

    return name

test = name_to_number("paper")

print test
```

Comment: `name1`, `name2` is a really common anti-pattern. Use a data structure (`list`, `dict`, etc...) instead. This kind of problem becomes trivial too.

Comment: Maybe you need enums: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Your real question is "How to map strings to numbers in Python" (or vice-versa). As the current title may be misleading, lets first address it for folks coming over "how to compare strings and numbers": unlike popular script languages Python will not make automatic type castings. For example, in Javascript you can do this:

```
>>> 5 == '5'
true
```

But in Python it is False:

```
>>> 5 == '5'
False
```

You must cast both values to the same type (for example `string` or `int`) explicitly if you expect them to be of different types:

```
>>> str(5) == str('5')
True
```

Now lets get back to your real question. As @GarethLatty commented:

> `name1`, `name2` is a really common anti-pattern. Use a data structure (list, dict, etc...) instead. This kind of problem becomes trivial too.

Two of the basic container data types in Python are the `list` and the `dict`.

Using a list:

```
>>> name_list = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']
>>> name_list.index('spock')
4
```

List indexes are zero-based:

```
>>> name_list[0]
'rock'
```

Using a dict you can associate arbitrary numbers to strings:

```
>>> name_dict = {'rock': 1, 'paper': 2, 'scissors': 3, 'lizard': 4, 'spock': 5}
>>> name_dict['spock']
5
```

If the value is not present in the list, the `index` method will raise a `ValueError` exception. In Python it is common to surround this kind of expression with a `try` block (like commented by icktoofay):

```
>>> name = 'kirk'
>>> try:
...     name_list.index(name)
... except ValueError:
...     print('{} is not a valid name.'.format(name)) 
... 
kirk is not a valid name.
```

This programming style is very popular. Using a `dict`, the exception you have to watch for is `KeyError`:

```
>>> name_dict['kirk']
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'kirk'
```

If you are starting with Python, the REPL (read-eval-print loop, the Python prompt) is your best friend. Just explore anything using the `help` and `dir` built-in functions:

```
>>> dir(name_dict)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__',
 '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key',
 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop',
 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys',
 'viewvalues']
>>> help(name_dict.keys)
Help on built-in function keys:

keys(...)
    D.keys() -> list of D's keys

>>>
```

Comment: For example, `name_to_number = lambda name: name_dict.get(name, -1)`, where if the name is not in name_dict it will return -1. But really, explore your options using the REPL and update your question with the results before asking again. This site is called stackoverflow, not domyhomeworkforme.