# short term for a class which instances are only used for variable storage?

Tags: c#, python, terminology

Something like a structure, how do you call that? I'm sure there is a shorter term then "class which instances are only used for variable storage"

Comment: Look at your post, this is not really a question. What do you want to know ? You are tagging to languages quite different and we don't even know what you want to do.

Comment: Well, there *is* a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ah19swz4.aspx) ...

Comment: I know there is struct, but i cant call a class a struct, that would be wrong

Comment: not answerable at all.what is the question?

Comment: Why use a class, when you *want* a struct? If all you need is "pass by reference", then maybe you can call it "structlike class" or something.

Comment: Are you looking for enumerated data type (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) or java enum (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  A way to implement in Python (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)

Comment: @Corak: What about Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it a Container class.

Comment: thats good, I call it that, thanks a lot!

Comment: I call it Scorpy. I like the name Scorpy.

Comment: well I am glad to be of help, although it seems to cost me my reputation :(. Weird system.

Comment: I believe the downvoter did not mean to disrespect your wish to help the OP, but the need for help in the first place, making the blame fall on you. I would consider a `Joke` category, so people could answer this question with serious, well phrased and funny jokes. Sounds better than a downvote, at least.

Comment: i accept it once i can, I don't really get why people would downvote a right answer without providing reason.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - Harvey is fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

DTO - Data Transfer Object comes to mind. Also Model or ViewModel.