# Is there any way to define the enum in python?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to define the enum just like below I do in JAVA and C?

```
C:
typedef enum status{
OFFLINE = 1,
ONLINE = 2,
LOGIN =3
} STATUS_T;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
OFFLINE = 1
ONLINE = 2
LOGIN = 3
```

You can wrap it in a class if you want `STATUS_T.OFFLINE` style of access. Python is a dynamically typed language so the concept of an enum makes little sense, all you can do is have range of meaningful values you can set something to.

Apparently, an equivalent has been added in 3.4, see [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

The most common idiom is to define a set of constants at the class level:

```
class PhonyEnum(object):
     OFFLINE = 1
     ONLINE = 2
     LOGIN = 3
```

It's up to you to  use them as constants:

```
if result == PhonyEnum.ONLINE: 
   do_something
```

Others also do the same thing at the module level rather than the class level