# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when creating an instance of object

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi next thing is bothering me:

I'm trying to use the next class:

```
class GameStatus(object):
"""Enum of possible Game statuses."""
__init__ = None
NotStarted, InProgress, Win, Lose = range(4)
def getStatus(number):
    return{
        0: "NotStarted",
        1: "InProgress",
        2: "Win",
        3: "Lose",
        }
```

in another class(both in same py file).
In this another class in his method **init** i do next thing:

```
class Game(object):
"""Handles a game of minesweeper by supplying UI to Board object."""
gameBoard = []
gs = ''
def __init__(self, board):
    self.gameBoard = board
    gs = GameStatus() //THIS IS THE LINE
```

And when i try to run the game i get next error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Dron6\Desktop\Study\Python\ex6\wp-proj06.py", line 423, in __init__
gs = GameStatus()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you do: `__init__ = None`

Comment: Also, why do you have a object that can easily be replaced by a dictionary, a list or a tuple?

Comment: Hmm.. i got this file as an interface. So i didn't write it.

Comment: Ok so the '__init__ = None' does the problem? If so can i use this class without an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after small research i found the problem.
The code i got was:

```
class GameStatus(object):
    """Enum of possible Game statuses."""
    __init__ = None
    NotStarted, InProgress, Win, Lose = range(4)
```

I needed to convert nymbers to their value.
So i build:

```
def getStatus(number):
return{
    0: "NotStarted",
    1: "InProgress",
    2: "Win",
    3: "Lose",
    }
```

And couldnt use it, because i couldn't create an object, and this mothod wasn't static.
The solution: Add @staticmethod before the method.

Plus i had one small error with the return switch, the correct version which works is:

```
@staticmethod
def getStatus(number):
return{
    0: "NotStarted",
    1: "InProgress",
    2: "Win",
    3: "Lose",
    }[number]
```

Thanks for all who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `GameStatus` initializer to `None`:

```
class GameStatus(object):
    __init__ = None
```

Don't do that. Python expects that to be a *method*. If you do not want to have a `__init__` method, *do not specify it at all*. At most, make it an empty function:

```
class GameStatus(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # Guaranteed to do nothing. Whatsoever. Whatever arguments you pass in.
        pass
```

If you wanted to create an enum-like object, take a look at [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)

For Python 2.7, you could use:

```
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    reverse = dict((value, key) for key, value in enums.iteritems())
    enums['reverse_mapping'] = reverse
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

GameStatus = enum('NotStarted', 'InProgress', 'Win', 'Lose')

print GameStatus.NotStarted          # 0
print GameStatus.reverse_mapping[0]  # NotStarted
```

Comment: Ok so the 'init = None' does the problem? If so can i use this class without an instance? –

Comment: Sorry for my stupid questions, its just that i'm new to python classes and don't understand them too well... :(

Comment: The class has been defined, and can be used. Not sure what use that'd be to you.