# Shared properties between classes and instances

Tags: python

Can anybody help at the question:
I need common property which is saved between call classes. Is there an opportunity does it? Please show examples.

Thanks!

UPDATED: Is there ability to share values between classes if opened two terminal?

Comment: If each terminal is opened with a different session of a Python interpreter, no, you can't share values between classes. You'll need an external mechanism for saving data if you intend to share it between sessions, for example a data base or a file

Comment: Thanks. Would it same at the `multiprocessing`?

Comment: No, `multiprocessing` controls the new processes for you; that won't work if you start new processes yourself.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to expose some knowledges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, assign it directly to your class:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = None  # shared

    def __init__(self):
        type(self).bar = 'baz'  # still shared, *per subclass*
        Foo.bar = 'baz'         # still shared, across all subclasses*
```

Any attribute on the class is shared between instances, unless you assign the same attribute name to the instance (which masks the class attribute). You can change that value by assigning directly to the class attribute, either via `type(self)` or by referencing the class name directly. By using `type(self)` subclasses can refer to their own class at all times.

Comment: I thank you for the answers and the tip about `type(self).bar`!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean, a *class* variable? like this:

```
class Test(object):
    class_variable = None # class variable, shared between all instances
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_variable = None # instance variable, one for each instance
```

For example:

```
a = Test()
b = Test()
Test.class_variable = 10
a.instance_variable = 20
b.instance_variable = 30

a.instance_variable
=> 20 # different values
b.instance_variable
=> 30 # different values

a.class_variable
=> 10 # same value
b.class_variable
=> 10 # same value
```

Comment: Is there ability to assign value to `Test.class_variable` at one module  and get same value from another module?

Comment: Sure, that should work as long as both are executing in the same session

Comment: Super duper big warning here: if you assign an instance's class variable to something else (which must be allocated), you are going to change its reference to the new object, but you won't update the class' variable itself. `Test.class_variable = 10; a.class_variable = "10"` now `a.class_variable` is the string `"10"` but `Test.class_variable` and `b.class_variable` will still be the *integer* `10`.

Answer (score 3):

I just [answered a question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242804/python-should-i-use-a-constant-or-a-property/17243194#17243194). Beware doing this class variable thing. It's possible, but you are not going to get what you expect.

```
>>> class Foo():
...     LABELS = ('One','Two','Three')
... 
>>> Foo.LABELS
('One', 'Two', 'Three')
>>> Foo.LABELS = (1,2,3)
>>> Foo.LABELS
(1, 2, 3)
>>> f = Foo()
>>> g = Foo()
>>> f.LABELS = ('a','b','c')
>>> g.LABELS
(1, 2, 3)
>>> Foo.LABELS
(1, 2, 3)
>>> f.LABELS
('a', 'b', 'c')
```