# How can I make this enum type support iteration?

Tags: python

After [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/371228) by Alec Thomas, I am using the following to create enumerations:

```
def enum(*sequential):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))))
    return type('Enum', (), enums)
```

I would like to be able to obtain the length of one of these enums. For example, I can write

```
>>> Suit = enum('spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs')
>>> Suit.spades
0
>>> Suit.hearts
1
>>> Suit.diamonds
2
>>> Suit.clubs
3
```

but there’s no way to list all of the enumeration values at runtime. I’d like to be able to do something like

```
>>> [s for s in Suit]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I’ve tried assigning `enum['__iter__']` within the `enum()` function, but I don’t know what kind of object I need to assign:

```
def enum(*sequential):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))))
    enums['__iter__'] = iter(range(len(sequential)))
    return type('Enum', (), enums)
```

gives

```
>>> [s for s in Suit]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

How can I give an `enum` the ability to list its members? (Even just the ability for the enum to report its length would suffice, since then the members are simply the elements of `range(len(Suit))`.)

Comment: @JoelCornett You can’t patch in the `__iter__`, see my answer.

Comment: @poke: >.< of course. You could instantiate and iterate, however. As in `list(Suit())`. Provided you've patched `__iter__`, that is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `type(…)` returns a *type*, i.e. something that’s actually used to create objects. Now of course you could argue if that’s a problem or not—and it’s likely not due to how Python’s typing system works (everything is an object, types are just objects of `type` objects etc.).

The effect however is that you can’t add special methods, like [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) which would be needed in this case. Special methods are however looked up on the type of the object, so in this case on `type` (which is the base type of the type you’re creating). And `type`—as you would expect—is not iterable.

So if you want to have something iterable, you will need to create something that is not a type. You could probably come up with some fancy meta class here, but the easiest thing you can do, which also keeps your code at the same length, is really a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). This is btw. also what the semantics in the Python 3.4 [`enum` type](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html) is inspired by.

```
>>> def enum(*keys):
        return namedtuple('Enum', keys)(*range(len(keys)))
>>> Suit = enum('spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs')
>>> Suit.spades
0
>>> Suit.hearts
1
>>> Suit.diamonds
2
>>> Suit.clubs
3
>>> [s for s in Suit]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use a different implementation of your `enumerator` by using [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

**Implementation**

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> def enum(*sequential):
    enums = namedtuple('enums',sequential)(*range(len(sequential)))
    return enums
```

**Usage**

```
>>> Suit = enum('spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs')
>>> Suit.spades
0
>>> Suit.hearts
1
>>> Suit.diamonds
2
>>> Suit.clubs
3
>>> [s for s in Suit]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to meet your requirements:

```
def enum(*sequential):
    length = len(sequential)
    pairs = zip(sequential, xrange(len(sequential)))
    Enum = type('Enum', (), dict(pairs))
    Enum.__len__ = lambda _: length
    Enum.__iter__ = lambda _: iter(range(length))
    return Enum()

Suit = enum('spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs')

print Suit.spades              # 0
print Suit.hearts              # 1
print Suit.diamonds            # 2
print Suit.clubs               # 3
print 'len(Suit):', len(Suit)  # len(Suit): 4
print [s for s in Suit]        # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variant works! with added `()` after `type(...)` to create class instance and modified `__iter__`:

```
def enum(*sequential):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))))
    enums['__iter__'] = lambda e,i=iter(range(len(sequential))): i
    return type('Enum', (object,), enums)()

>>> suit = enum('spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs')
>>> [s for s in suit]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```