# Looking for a data type able to hold only specific values

Tags: python, list, switch-statement, selection

I have recently started with Python again, and I am trying to write a module where lots of problems of the following kind occur:

An object `Problem` can hold a variable `Unit`. Unit can only be either "inches", "millimeters" or "meters".

The module is supposed to be used by others, so I want the most easily usable solution to this. If possible I want the user to receive an error if they try to assign anything but one of those values.

I see this would be possible with objects where I define a `unitClass` class that inherits to daughter classes `inchesClass`, `millimetersClass` and `metersClass`. I would then make an instance of each, that the user can assign to the variable in question. But I think this might be confusing, unless that is a standard way to go about such a problem?

The other solution I came up with was set methods but since I don't use them for other variables, I wanted to avoid them in this case as well if possible.

Is there another way to do this using just the modules provided by a standard python installation?

Regards,

RTT

Comment: Are we working in python 3 or python not 3?

Comment: I wanted to make it compatible with 2.7, but it isn't a high priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other languages (namely java), this kind of structure is called an `enum` or enumeration. Specifically because you enumerate the possible values for something.

In python 3, you can import enum and use it like so:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):

    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

There's a post that goes more in depth here: [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)

If you want an example of how to extend this to your specific case I'd do it like so, by creating a Unit enum:

```
class Unit(Enum):
    inches, millimeters, meters = range(3)

class Problem(object):

    def __init__(self, units):
        self.unit = getattr(Unit(), units)
```

Comment: I'd like to add that `enum` was only added in Python 3.4 and that is hardly available in most production environments.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 import from __future__

Comment: Good point. I always implemented it myself, because it really isn't hard to do...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to restrict the possible values for a property of an object without usimgna setter function. In Python you can have getters/setters that behave like usual properties. You can do:

```
class Problem(object):
    @property
    def unit(self):
        return self._unit

    @unit.setter
    def unit(self, val):
        if val in ["inches", "millimeters", "meters"]:
            self._unit = val
```

I changed `Unit` because variables that are not types vor singletons usually shouldn't start in upper case.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but this was also helpful. Thank you.