# How does this "enumeration" idiom work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enumeration

I've been using this for a while - I can't recall where I found it:

```
#####
#  An enumeration is handy for defining types of event 
#  (which otherwise would messily be just random strings)

def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

#####
#   The control events that the Controller can process
#   Usually this would be in a module imported by each of M, V and C
#   These are the possible values for the "event" parameter of an APP_EVENT message

AppEvents = enum(APP_EXIT = 0,
                 CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT = 1,
                 CUSTOMER_WITHDRAWAL = 2)
```

How does it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/1957346

Comment: Right - but I'm stuck on 2.7 till wxpython moves...

Comment: You should still be able to use the new `Enum` definition. It's been backported to Python 2.4+, so it's available. :)

Comment: Oh - cool!  :)  I'll have to check that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When called in that way, `type` declares a type dynamically. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#type):

> With three arguments, return a new type object. *This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement.* The name string is the class name and becomes the **name** attribute; the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the **bases** attribute; and the dict dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the **dict** attribute.

So the type name is 'Enum' and there are no base classes.

The `enum` function has a `**enums` argument, which takes all named parameters and puts them into a dictionary object.

In your case, the `enums` variable is

```
{
    'APP_EXIT': 0,
    'CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT':  1,
    'CUSTOMER_WITHDRAWAL': 2,
}
```

Those become the attributes of the returned type.

---

FYI, [`Enum`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) has been added to Python 3.4 and [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) to 2.4+. (see also [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python/1695250#1695250)).

Comment: Thanks!   What is the meaning of ** in the parameter list?