# Limit argument to specific values in python

Tags: python

If I have python function with a string argument which needs to be in a specific list of values, what's the best way to handle this? Is there a convention to expressing this in the docstrings or anything?

eg.

```
def makeShape(shape):
   assert shape in ["circle", "square", "triangle"]
```

Is there a nicer way to express that shape should always be one of those three values?

Comment: If this function is part of a class, perhaps making that list a sort of class constant... Other than that, looks good to me.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you are using a string and what are your fundamental constraints? Could the enum idea suggested by @blue-ice be what you really need?

Comment: Ok - maybe my example is a bit misleading as in that case you could create a class for each shape. My problem (this time - it seems to come up a lot though) is that I have an interface which runs in three modes: Load, Save and View. I want to pass a "mode" arg, but it can only be one of those three values. The Enum solution is very nice, but I'm on python2.6 unfortunately (in maya and nuke).

Comment: @ninhenzo64 As noted in a comment on my answer, `enum`s have been backported to 2.6 through pypi. It should be do-able for you.

Answer (score 11):

You could use an `enum` for the correct sort of shapes:

```
class rightShape(Enum):
    circle = 1
    square = 2
    triangle = 3

def makeShape(rightShape):
    # code in function
```

This will throw an honest-to-goodness error if you try to pass the function anything but a `circle`, `square`, or `triangle`.

Comment: Since the latest Ubuntu only has 3.3, I think it's worth noting that Enum's are new in python 3.4.

Comment: @jrennie However, it has been backported from 3.4 to earlier versions- see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python).

Comment: This does not raise an error though? It just accepts anything because of Pythons duck-typing? Isn't this answer simply wrong?

Comment: This does not seem to be working in python3

Comment: `makeShape(5)` will not throw an exception or show a warning.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a genuine error, you should raise an exception. I think TypeError would be a reasonable choice, but you may want to define your own.

`assert` statements are for development. Note that they are ignored when the `-O` argument is used, so they should not be relied upon to catch errors.

Answer (score 2):

I personally also would prefer the [`enum` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418160/1864294), but I would like to highlight another, also very commonly used solution via [`typing`'s `Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal):

```
from typing import Literal

PossibleShapes = Literal["circle", "square", "triangle"]

def makeShape(shape: PossibleShapes):
    ...
```

Comment: `makeShape(5)` will not throw an exception or show a warning.

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with the solution discussed above. This is Python and it's dynamic typing: the type declaration is not enforced. Just search for "type hints" or see https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [Blue Ice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180567/blue-ice) - thank you for the push to the enum direction.

As I stumbled over the same issue, this is my working example, also raising a type error.

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python3

    from enum import Enum

    class InvalidParameters(Enum):
        ''' This is used to demonstrate the type error. '''
        ILLEGAL = 0

    class ValidParameters(Enum):
        ''' This is used to pass a valid parameter. '''
        LEGAL = 0

    def someFunc(param : ValidParameters) -> None:
        ''' Do some necessary stuff. '''
        if not type(param) is ValidParameters:
            raise TypeError('Parameter has to be of type ValidParameters')
        print(f'{ValidParameters(param)}')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ''' Some test cases, dis-/enable them one by one. '''
        someFunc('Wrong')
        #someFunc(InvalidParameters.ILLEGAL)
        #someFunc(ValidParameters.LEGAL)
        SystemExit(0)
```