# String-based indices in tuple Python

Tags: python, tuples

Is it possible to create a tuple in Python with indices that are string-based, not number based? That is, if I have a tuple of `("yellow", "fish", "10)`, I would be able to access by `[color]` instead of `[0]`. This is really only for the sake of convenience.

Comment: You might want to look into using a dictionary instead http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm or Enums can be another option but they were only introduced in later versions of python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python

Comment: Why not a dictionary?

Comment: [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> MyObject = namedtuple('MyObject', 'color number')
>>> my_obj = MyObject(color="yellow", number=10)
>>> my_obj.color
'yellow'
>>> my_obj.number
10
```

And you can still access items by index:

```
>>> my_obj[0]
'yellow'
>>> my_obj[1]
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `collections.namedtuple` does this, although you'll access the color with `x.color` rather than `x['color']`