# NamedTuple declaration and use in a single line

Tags: python, namedtuple

I would like to store a dimension `namedtuple` `(x, y)`. I will only need this once in my entire program.

I could do:

```
Dimension = namedtuple('Dimension', ['x', 'y'])
dim = Dimension(2, 3)
```

but, since I'm sure this is the only `Dimension` I will need in the entire program, I was wondering if I could make this into one-liner that returns an object whose properties I can access like `dim.x` and `dim.y`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Guess this was a really dumb question then! Seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe how about posting it as an answer so the OP can accept and people can upvote? :)

Comment: There are some enum classes that let you do this... which python version are you on? two different ones are in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python . with the standard python3+ one, it looks like this: `dimension = Enum('Dimension', (('x',2),('y', 3)))`, and with the older version (which I prefer, and have some classes based on) you do it like this: `dimension = Enum(x=2, y=3)`...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no need for the temporary name `Dimension`:

```
dim = namedtuple('Dimension', ['x', 'y'])(2, 3)
```

Alternatively, you can use the three-argument form of [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to create a new class and create an instance of it:

```
dim = type('Dimension', (object,), {'x': 2, 'y': 3})()
```

This object will use more memory but, unlike the `namedtuple`, will be mutable (this may or may not be a good thing for your use cases). It also saves an `import`.

Answer (score 6):

I've come across this issue myself a lot; what *would* be great is if the Python standard library had the following convenience function built in to the `collections` module. But in lieu of that, you can always define this yourself locally:

```
def make_namedtuple(class_name, **fields):
    return namedtuple(class_name, fields)(*fields.values())
```

With this you could instantiate a new, single-use namedtuple class for a single instance like so:

```
dim = make_namedtuple('Dimension', x=2, y=3)
```

This works **for Python 3.6+[1]**.

[1] the `**fields`' order is not maintained on Python versions <3.6 (in other words, pre-[PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/)). You can still use the function, but it kind of defeats the purpose of having a class that unpacks like a tuple, imo...