# mapping 2 list of unequal length to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scipy

I am trying to create a dictionary of colors where an integer maps to a color.
In my first list l1, it has 177 items but only 5 unique integers (0 to 4).
In the second list, it has 5 html colors.
I am trying to create a dictionary where each color will map to a unique integer.

```
 l1=[3 2 3 3 0 2 4 4 2 3 2 2 4 0 3 2 2 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 0 3 1 0 2 2 2 4 2 4 2 0
     2 0 4 0 4 2 0 2 2 2 4 1 3 2 2 2 1 0 3 3 2 0 2 3 4 1 0 0 1 3 1 3 1 4 3 4 1
     4 0 2 3 2 0 4 1 3 0 0 4 0 4 0 2 2 1 2 2 1 0 4 4 3 1 3 2 2 2 4 4 2 0 3 4 4
     0 3 4 3 4 2 2 2 3 3 1 0 2 3 1 1 4 0 1 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 3 1 0 3 3 3 2 2 3
     3 0 0 0 2 0 3 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 4 3 3 0 2 2 3 2 3 3 0 2 0 4 3]

 l2=['#000000', '#FFFFFF', '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF']
```

Here is my code:

```
    color_map=dict(zip(l1,l2))
    print color_map
```

However, I get an incocomplete dictionary:

```
{0: '#0000FF', 2: '#FFFFFF', 3: '#00FF00'}
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: in order to use `zip` and get a perfect match, you need two lists/sets of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You need a set so you get all unique numbers from `l`:

```
print(dict(zip(set(l)),l2))
{0: '#000000', 1: '#FFFFFF', 2: '#FF0000', 3: '#00FF00', 4: '#0000FF'}
```

If you always want the numbers sorted:

```
 print(dict(zip(sorted(set(l)),l2)))
```

You will always need to have only 5 unique values in `l` if you only have five values in `l2` or again you will lose data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you've presented, I would suggest considering an [`enum.Enum` or `enum.IntEnum` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/2437514) instead of a dictionary ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)). It's hard to say for sure, but `IntEnum` may work better for you here.

You can create your `IntEnum` this way:

```
l2=['#000000', '#FFFFFF', '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF']
from enum import IntEnum
Color = IntEnum('Color', ' '.join(l2))
```

Now all of your colors have been automatically mapped to an integer value (beginning with 1; the reason for starting with 1 instead of zero is so that all members of an `Enum` evaluate to `True`).

You can iterate over `Color` and access member names and member values, similar to how you would with a dictionary:

```
for color in Color:
    print(color.name, color.value)
```

Notice that when you access the member by key like in a dictionary, the `IntEnum` member object itself is returned, *not* the integer it's mapped to:

```
print(Color['#000000'])
```

...however, this probably won't matter to you, because since it's an `IntEnum` the member objects act like integers, including for the purposes of comparison, etc:

```
for color in Color:
    if color == 1:
        print(color.name, ' is 1!')

print(Color['#000000'] == 1) # will print either True or False 
c = Color(1)
print(c) # will print the Color member c, which is mapped to 1
```

The above is the key reason I am thinking this may be a better alternative. Your `l1` list is full of integers that represent colors. The ideal thing would be to fill it with `Color` members instead of integers:

```
for index, number in enumerate(l1):
    l1[index] = Color(number)
```

However, if you can't/don't want to do that, you can still compare the integers to the `Color` members (I assume you don't have any interest in "adding", "multiplying", etc, colors together).

So, you could maybe do things like this:

```
print(any(number == Color['#000000'] for number in l1))
```

The `Color` enum also comes with a built-in dictionary object (`Color.__members__`) that will return a dictionary with the member names as the keys and the member itself as the value.

Answer (score 0):

If the unique integers are consecutive, you can use `enumerate()`:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(l2))
{0: '#000000', 1: '#FFFFFF', 2: '#FF0000', 3: '#00FF00', 4: '#0000FF'}
```

Comment: this will always get `0,1,2,3,4` not necessarily the five unique values from l

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, but potentially the values in the first list are always such numbers and then this is the easiest solution. If not, use one of the other solutions.

Comment: yes but  `5,6,7,8,9 ` are also consecutive numbers.

Comment: Well yeah, consecutive and starting at `0` - that's what I meant based on what we happen to see in the given `l1` list.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `set()` to get all the unique integer of l1:

```
l1_list=list(set([3,2,3,3,0,2,4,4,2,3,2,2,4,0,3,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,2,2,0,3,1,0,2,2,2,4,2,4,2,0,2,0,4,0,4,2,0,2,2,2,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,0,3,3,2,0,2,3,4,1,0,0,1,3,1,3,1,4,3,4,1,4,0,2,3,2,0,4,1,3,0,0,4,0,4,0,2,2,1,2,2,1,0,4,4,3,1,3,2,2,2,4,4,2,0,3,4,4,0,3,4,3,4,2,2,2,3,3,1,0,2,3,1,1,4,0,1,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,3,1,0,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,0,0,0,2,0,3,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,4,3,3,0,2,2,3,2,3,3,0,2,0,4,3]))
l2=['#000000', '#FFFFFF', '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF']

color_map=dict(zip(l1_list,l2))
print color_map
```

Output:

```
{0: '#000000', 1: '#FFFFFF', 2: '#FF0000', 3: '#00FF00', 4: '#0000FF'}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Simeon Visser's answer is the most concise one for the specific example you provided (using integers from 0 to 4). But, if what you wanted is to have a sequence of #s like `{0: '#0000FF', 2: '#FFFFFF', 3: '#00FF00'}` where all the items show up from the original list (even repeated), this won't work.

It seems your intention, however, was to actually grab the colors for all the corresponding items of the list. If that's the case, what you *can* do is use Simeon's answer and combine it with your original list like in the following way:

```
colorDict = dict(enumerate(l2))
colors = [colorDict[colorIndex] for colorIndex in l1]
```

This will map all the colors to a new list based on the integer sequence from `l1`. Hope that helps.