# Converting to Functional style

Tags: python, functional-programming

I wrote the following method in python that finds the intersection of 2 segments on a plane (assuming the segments are parallel to either the x or y axis)

> segment_endpoints = []
>
> def intersection(s1, s2):
>
> ```
>    segment_endpoints = []
>
>    left = max(min(s1[0], s1[2]), min(s2[0], s2[2]))
>    right = min(max(s1[0], s1[2]), max(s2[0], s2[2]))
>    top = max(min(s1[1], s1[3]), min(s2[1], s2[3]))
>    bottom = min(max(s1[1], s1[3]), max(s2[1], s2[3]))
>
>    if top > bottom or left > right:
>       segment_endpoints = []
>       return 'NO INTERSECTION'       
>
>    elif top == bottom and left == right:
>       segment_endpoints.append(left)
>       segment_endpoints.append(top)
>       return 'POINT INTERSECTION'
>
>    else:  
>       segment_endpoints.append(left)
>       segment_endpoints.append(bottom)
>       segment_endpoints.append(right)
>       segment_endpoints.append(top)         
>       return 'SEGMENT INTERSECTION'
> ```

Can this be considered in good functional form? If not what would be the proper functional way of rewriting it?

Comment: `Can this be considered in good functional form?` - This is kind of opinionated question.

Comment: I agree. I wrote it in procedural form as I dont know much about the functional style of programming. I was curious if there is a more "proper" functional style

Answer (score 1):

I think the code can be refactored as follows, but not necessarily a functional style.

```
def intersection(s1, s2):

    left = max(min(s1[0], s1[2]), min(s2[0], s2[2]))
    right = min(max(s1[0], s1[2]), max(s2[0], s2[2]))
    top = max(min(s1[1], s1[3]), min(s2[1], s2[3]))
    bottom = min(max(s1[1], s1[3]), max(s2[1], s2[3]))

    if top > bottom or left > right:
        return ('NO INTERSECTION',dict())
    if (top,left) == (bottom,right):
        return ('POINT INTERSECTION',dict(left=left,top=top))
    return ('SEGMENT INTERSECTION',dict(left=left,bottom=bottom,right=right,top=top))
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the conciseness of it.

Answer (score -1):

You are abusing strings. I would consider returning integers instead of strings and defining something like:

```
class IntersectionType:
  NO_INTERSECTION = 1
  POINT_INTERSECTION = 2
  SEGMENT_INTERSECTION = 3
```

Python 3.4 also contains enums: [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) ... so if you're using Python 3.4 then this would be a use case for enums.