# Creating C like Enum in Python

Tags: python, c, enums

Maybe I have already found the answer to this question in that it's not possible, but if there's a nifty trick... I'm all ears.  I'm trying to reproduce the following C enumeration list in python:

```
enum Id
{
   NONE = 0,
   HEARTBEAT, //0x1
   FLUID_TRANSFER_REQUEST,
   FLUID_TRANSFER_STATUS_MSG,
   FLUID_TRANSFER_ERROR_MSG,
   FLUID_TRANSFER_RESUME,
   EMERGENCY_STOP_MSG,
   LOG_MSG,
   VERSION_REQUEST,
   VERSION_RESPONSE,
   CHANNEL_INFORMATION_REQUEST,
   CHANNEL_INFORMATION_RESPONSE,
   TEST_REQUEST,
   LED_CONTROL_REQ,
   RESET_REQ,

   // Camera App Messages
   START_SENDING_PICTURES = 0x010000,
   STOP_SENDING_PICTURES,
   START_RECORDING_VIDEO_REQ,
   STOP_RECORDING_VIDEO_REQ,
   TAKE_PICTURE_REQ,
   SET_VOLUME_LIMIT,         
   VIDEO_FRAME_MSG,
   PICTURE_MSG,
   I_FRAME_REQUEST,
   CURRENT_VOLUME,
   START_ANALYZING_IMAGES_REQ,
   STOP_ANALYZING_IMAGES_REQ,
   SET_FILE_PATH,

   //Sensor Calibration
   VOLUME_REQUEST = 0x020000,
   START_CAL,
   CLI_COMMAND_REQUEST,
   CLI_COMMAND_RESPONSE,

   // File Mananger
   NEW_DELIVERY_REQ = 0x30000,
   GET_DELIVERY_FILE_REQ,
   GET_FILE_REQ,

   ACK_NACK,
   RESPONSE,

   LAST_ID
};
```

However, I don't want to have to specify every value for the list because it's changing often.  Since I also have it set to a new value in the various sections, I can't use the AutoNumber methodology (e.g. VOLUME_REQUEST = 0x020000).  Anyone got a clever trick to reproduce C style enums in python, or am I stuck with reproducing it the hard way?

Comment: @David, I did see before I posted [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) but I didn't think it answered my specific request in a good way.  I believe the answers below are much better served for this particular request.

Comment: The answers here are a subset of, and a pale imitation, of the answers there. I suggest that you read those answers more closely.

Comment: I just went through those answers, and none of them address the OP's question.  If you are curious about my credentials: I'm the primary author of the [Enum data type](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html), and of the [enum34 backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new [aenum library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) by the author of [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) which has a few extra goodies (such as a class-based `NamedTuple` and a `Constant` class).

One of the cool features available if you are using Python 3 is the built-in auto-numbering:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Id(Enum, start=0):
    #
    _auto_on_                   # needed since aenum 3.0
    #
    NONE  # 0x0
    HEARTBEAT  # 0x1
    FLUID_TRANSFER_REQUEST
    FLUID_TRANSFER_STATUS_MSG
    FLUID_TRANSFER_ERROR_MSG
    # ...
    # Camera App Messages
    START_SENDING_PICTURES = 0x010000
    STOP_SENDING_PICTURES
    START_RECORDING_VIDEO_REQ
    STOP_RECORDING_VIDEO_REQ
    # ...
    # Sensor Calibration
    VOLUME_REQUEST = 0x020000
    START_CAL
    CLI_COMMAND_REQUEST
    CLI_COMMAND_RESPONSE
    #
    # File Mananger
    NEW_DELIVERY_REQ = 0x30000
    GET_DELIVERY_FILE_REQ
    GET_FILE_REQ
    #
    ACK_NACK
    RESPONSE
    #
    LAST_ID
```

and in use:

```
print(repr(Id.HEARTBEAT))
# <Id.HEARTBEAT: 1>

print(repr(Id.STOP_SENDING_PICTURES))
# <Id.STOP_SENDING_PICTURES: 65537>

print(repr(Id.VOLUME_REQUEST))
# <Id.VOLUME_REQUEST: 131072>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool and may be the cleanest, simplest solution, but I didn't have the library at the time.  And I believe we were limited to what external libraries we could include.  Nice solution though @Ethan :)

Comment: @ls6777:  Thanks!  If you like it, it's okay to up-vote it.  ;)

Comment: I did upvote, but it won't publicly display until I have 15 rep points ;)

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thanks!

Comment: @roberto:  More details, please -- I just tested with the latest versions of aenum and Python and it worked fine.

Comment: yes it runs, but i was confused by the fact that pycharm underlines in red indicating 'Unresolved ref NONE' and all the rest

Comment: @roberto: Thank you, that's a much more useful comment.  And you're right -- linters, etc., will not be happy with the above code, or other code shenanigans (such as modifying `globals()` to create variables).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use some variant of [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) in Python 3. For Python 2, I simply did the following (with parentheses to avoid an ugly `\` at the end of each line):

```
(T_OR, T_AND, T_NOT,
 T_OPEN_PAREN, T_CLOSE_PAREN,
 T_EQUAL, T_UNEQUAL,
 ...
 T_DEFCONFIG_LIST, T_MODULES, T_VISIBLE) = range(0, 39)
```

To handle multiple ranges, just use multiple separate `range()` assignments. The downside is that you have to specify the final value explicitly.

There seems to be some fancier methods in [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) too, but the above should be closest to a C-style `enum` with minimal syntactic overhead.

Not a serious suggestion, but if you enjoy cryptic code and questionable practices, then the hack below seems to work as well for a C-style `enum` (with the caveat that the enumerators are always created at module scope). Feel free to harp on it. ;)

```
def create_var_range(first_val, *names):
    for name in names:
        globals()[name] = first_val
        first_val += 1

create_var_range(0,
                 "NONE",
                 "HEARTBEAT",
                 ...)

create_var_range(0x010000,
                 "START_SENDING_PICTURES",
                 "STOP_SENDING_PICTURES",
                 ...)
```

`create_var_range()` steps through its variable argument list of names and creates a variable for each, assigning increasing integer values starting from `first_val`. It makes use of the `globals()` function, which return a dictionary with the global symbol table.

Comment: Thanks! I think this and @Saturisk answers will work for my purposes.  I just need to pick which one I want to use :)

Answer (score 4):

Please see the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for Python 3.4 if this is applicable. I wrote my code based off of what I found here.

This is mostly a hack because I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to solve what I have done.

```
from enum import IntEnum
import re

class AutoNumber(IntEnum):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        numberList = re.findall(r'\d+', str(cls._member_map_))
        if len(cls.__members__) > 0 and not args:
            prevMax = max(map(int, numberList))
            value = prevMax + 1
            print(format(value, '#04x'))
        else:
            value = args[0]
            print(format(value, '#04x'))

        integer = int.__new__(cls)
        integer._value_ = value
        return integer

class EnumClass(AutoNumber):
   NONE = 0
   HEARTBEAT = () # 0x1
   FLUID_TRANSFER_REQUEST = ()
   # ...

   # Camera App Messages
   START_SENDING_PICTURES = 0x010000
   STOP_SENDING_PICTURES = ()
   START_RECORDING_VIDEO_REQ = ()
   # ...

   # Sensor Calibration
   VOLUME_REQUEST = 0x020000
   START_CAL = ()
   # ...

   # File Mananger
   NEW_DELIVERY_REQ = 0x30000
   GET_DELIVERY_FILE_REQ = ()
   GET_FILE_REQ = ()
   # ...
```

This 'enum' outputs are effectively:

```
0x00 # NONE
0x01
0x02
...
0x10000 # START_SENDING_PICTURES
0x10001
0x10002
...
0x20000 # VOLUME_REQUEST
0x20001
...
0x30000 # NEW_DELIVERY_REQ
0x30001
0x30002
...
```

Note, the output is when the item is created using the print statement, it was meant for debug purposes, but it's the nicest way I could get the data to come out.

Comment: I updated with working code. This is mostly a hack, but effectively works as a self-updating enumeration.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of the `= ()` after each enum, but this does the job that I want.  Thanks!