# Mixing auto instances and strings in Python3 enum values

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I am building a general-purpose NLP pipeline that will be able to use one of the several state-of-the-art NLP libraries currently out there. The library and exact model to use will be specified when instantiating the general purpose pipe. For this, I have created an enum whose values will be passed over to the general pipe's init and looks like this for now (only the spaCy part is ready):

```
@unique
class LibrKey(Enum):
    """NLP-library to use."""
    CUSTOM = auto()
    SPACY_SM = "en_core_web_sm"
    SPACY_MD = "en_core_web_md"
    SPACY_LG = "en_core_web_lg"
    SPACY_TR = "en_core_web_trf"
    STANZA = auto()
    TRANKIT = auto()
```

I was wondering, however, about the correctness of having both auto instances and strings as values for the enum. According to the latest enum docu, namely, https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html care should be taken in these cases:

> Member values can be anything: int, str, etc.. If the exact value is
> unimportant you may use auto instances and an appropriate value will
> be chosen for you. Care must be taken if you mix auto with other
> values.

So I was also wondering what is exactly meant with having to take care here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that mixing auto-assigned numeric values and manually assigned numeric values could end up duplicating values.  The `Enum` and `IntEnum` `auto()` use the last value seen and increment by one, so it's possible to specify a value already given by `auto()` and end up with an alias instead of a unique member:

```
class Confused(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()
    FOUR = auto()
    TRIANGLE = 3
    FIVE = auto()
```

In the above enumeration, `FIVE` is an alias to `FOUR`.

In certain situations mixing them can be quite effective, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965438/208880) (slightly different syntax, same idea).

Using `None` or `Ellipsis` (or identical or same-valued object) as a placeholder could be a bad idea, depending on your usage -- using the identical or same-valued objects means only the first one is unique, all the others are aliases (and would fail if using the `Unique` decorator).  If you want to be absolutely clear about which ones are not yet usable, you can create your own `_generate_next_value_` (which is what `auto()` uses):

```
def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values, *args, **kwds):
    return '%s not implemented' % (name, )
```

which would result in:

```
>>> list(LibrKey)
[
  <LibrKey.CUSTOM: 'CUSTOM not implemented'>,
  <LibrKey.SPACY_SM: 'en_core_web_sm'>,
  <LibrKey.SPACY_MD: 'en_core_web_md'>,
  <LibrKey.SPACY_LG: 'en_core_web_lg'>,
  <LibrKey.SPACY_TR: 'en_core_web_trf'>,
  <LibrKey.STANZA: 'STANZA not implemented'>,
  <LibrKey.TRANKIT: 'TRANKIT not implemented'>,
  ]
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Very clear explanation @Ethan Furman. Thanks!