# How to perform a pairwise swap of a list?

Tags: python

I want to write a small code in python that Swap Elements in a list this program will accept a list, and will return a list that exchanges the positions of each pair of adjacent elements: positions 0 and 1, positions 2 and 3, and so on.  If the list has an odd number of elements, then the element in the last position stays “in place”.

```
Before: [1,2,3,4,5]
After: [2,1,4,3,5]
```

This looks unpythonic. What is the Python way to do it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: Read up on how to write a good question that's [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "How do I <assignment>?" Plus some effort. See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pairwise-swap-elements-of-a-given-linked-list/

Comment: ...though highly popular questions appear to validate [a lack of shown effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python?rq=1). Perhaps SO fears answers not being accepted or useful enough (a little personal info about what you need it for would help) but that's not the reason why this question is on hold.

Comment: Sure, Cees's answer seems like a perfect fit for this question.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - This question has been reopened. Feel free to move your answer to SO if you feel like it.

Answer (score 5):

Most pythonic way:

```
def swappairwise(a):
  l = len(a)&~1
  a[1:l:2],a[:l:2] = a[:l:2],a[1:l:2]
```

Comment: I don't understand `&-` but your code works and is 50+ chars shorter than mine.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Its binary `and` with all 1 except first, to round down to even number.

Comment: I guessed as much, but thought the negative sign was a single bit. [I was wrong.](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-bitwise-shift-negative-number/)

Comment: ...provided the hardware uses [two's complement notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and 2 is not a [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point value. I'd use `&~1` instead of `&-2`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a neat one, if you are always guaranteed to have `even` numbers:

```
 nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 print([nums[i^1] for i in range(len(nums))])
 >>[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

**Explanation:**

```
print (0^1)    #1
print (1^1)    #0
print (2^1)    #3
print (3^1)    #2
print (4^1)    #5
print (5^1)    #4
```

As a refresher, the `XOR` has the following effect:

```
A   B | Output
---------------
0   0     0
0   1     1
1   0     1
1   1     0
```

**And the official description:** Each bit of the output is the same as the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, and it's the complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer above from @Arpegius, here a, hopefully, somewhat more readable solution. Uses the same approach.

```
def swap_list_pairwise(lis):
    """Pairwise swap of all elements in a list.

    If the number of elements is odd, the leftover element
    stays at its place.
    """
    length = len(lis)  
    # Stop at second last if length is odd, otherwise use full list. 
    end = length - 1 if length % 2 else length
    lis[1:end:2], lis[:end:2] = lis[:end:2], lis[1:end:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want "pythonic", try ["How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python), followed by a [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) that reverses every chunk. May not be too performant, though.

(Oh, forgot the [flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) of the list at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
def pairwise_swap(iterable):
    for i, value in enumerate(iterable):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            saved = value
        else:
            yield value
            yield saved

>>> list(pairwise_swap(range(10)))
[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8]
```

Comment: This swallows the last element if the number of elements in the iterable is odd. I modified your solution a bit. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nice approach by @Alok above. This should fix the missing last
element if the number of elements is odd.

```
def pairwise_swap(iterable):
    """Pairwise swap of all elements in an iterable.

    If the number of elements is odd, the leftover element
    stays at its place.
    """
    for i, value in enumerate(iterable):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            saved = value
        else:
            yield value
            yield saved
    # Don't forget the last element if `iterable` has an odd 
    # number of elements. Since counting starts a zero, we need 
    # to test if `i` is even. 
    if iterable and i % 2 == 0:
        yield value
```

Comment: This should've been an edit or comment on Alok's answer.

Comment: @Cees I added a comment at Alok’s answer as well. I tried to put my additions there first. But the code seemed rather difficult to read. Therefore I decided to reference the original in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this one out?

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> pl = [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
>>> pl
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> for i in pl:
...     i[0],i[1] = i[1],i[0]
...     print i
... 
[2, 1]
[4, 3]
[6, 5]
>>> pl
[[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
>>> 
>>> zpl = [i for sublist in pl for i in sublist]
>>> zpl
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
>>>
```

I tried to resolve in the easiest way out.

Comment: I will be happy to know how others who have posted answers here feel about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
It will work for both even and odd elements. if list elements are even 
first part will work if not else will do his task.

a = list(input("Put your list here: "))
len_a = len(a)
last_element = len_a-1

result = 0
if len_a % 2==0:
        for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
                a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
        print("its if",a)

else:
        a_n = a.pop()
        for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
                a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
        a.insert(0,a_n)
        # a.insert(last_element,a_n) if you want last element remain unmodified
        print("its else:",a)
```

Comment: tnx for your suggestion David :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Hopefully, it can help others. I think about using boxes. The value in the first position needs a temporary place to be before it can be swapped, so I assign it to x and then make the swap. Incrementing by 2 will skip over the last element, so it's okay with odd-numbered lists as well.

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
i = 0
while i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
    x = a[i]
    a[i] = a[i + 1]
    a[i + 1] = x
    i += 2
print(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Found this to be much simpler solution and handels the list with odd elements

```
elements = list(map(int,input().split()))
swap = []

i = 0
while i < len(elements):
    if i+1 < len(elements):
        swap.append(elements[i+1])
        swap.append(elements[i]) 
    else:
        swap.append(elements[-1])
    i = i+2
print(swap)
```