# How does one implement in python the equivalent of a C++ class member that returns a pointer to another class?

Tags: python, c++, pointers

With a background in C++, I am currently trying to learn Python and am trying to understand how to write code without pointers. In a specific example, I would like to know how to implement the following C++ code in Python:

```
class Room: public MapSite
{
public:
Room(int roomNo);
MapSite* GetSide(Direction) const;  // Direction is an enum
void SetSide(Direction, MapSite*);
virtual void Enter();    // An inherited method from MapSite class

private:
MapSite* sides(4);
int  roomNo;
}
```

The above example comes from

> Desgin Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

I want to know how you would implement the above in Python, specifically the GetSide() function and the sides variable that utilize a pointer to another class. Thank you.

## Edit:

What I wanted to know originally, without fully realizing it at first, was how the C++ class I provided could be implemented in a Pythonic way. I now realize that is too broad of a request, though some of the answers were helpful to me and set me on the right path.

Comment: Why don't you show us what have you written in Python?

Comment: I think it would be easier for people to answer if you described in *words* what you want to achieve, at least for us who doesn't know much C++.

Comment: Maybe start by writing some valid C++. Or do you want some python code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some differences with C++: In Python, everything is an object, and variables contain references to objects, rather then the objects themselves. If you want an object of a class to have attributes, assign them in the constructor named __init__. Each member function including the constructor has a first parameter self. Whenever you call members f or use attributes a you'll have to add the 'self', so self.f () and self.a. Note that you in fact are constantly working with "dereferenced pointers" (references). One of the main pitfalls for C++ programmers is to conclude that you can return a value in a function parameter since it is a reference. If however you assign to a function parameter inside a function, it will after that be a reference to the newly assigned object. So the object passed by the caller will not be altered. I advise you to work through some Python tutorials and also pay attention to Cython, since it will allow you to combine your C++ and Python knowledge.

Your program would look something like:

```
class Room (MapSite):
    def __init__ (self, room_no):
        self._room_no = room_no
        self._map_site = None

    def get_side (self, direction):
        return ...

    def set_side(self, direction, map_site):
        ...

    # No need to define enter since it is inherited
```

Comment: In C++ everything is an object too. So a C++ object probably has a different meaning to a python object.

Comment: @juanchopanza: True, stricktly spoken even a C++  pointer is an object.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that *any* variable or attribute is a reference in Python. If you want to store an object as an attribute of a class, just assign it; Python stores the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain as much as I can do for each of the lines in your code

> class Room: public MapSite {

To declare a class `Room` which inherits `MapSite` you can do

```
class Room(MapSite):
```

in Python. Here `MapSite` must also be a class to be inherited.

> public:
>   Room(int roomNo);

To declare a constructor in a class, you can use `__init__` in Python.

```
def __init__(self, roomNo)
```

Now, how can you write `enum` in Python? You can do that by `enum` module
Please refer : [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python?rq=1)

Concerning the `private` or `public` keywords in C++, you don't need them here directly as such tokens are not defined in Python.

I don't know how much more help you want. It would be better if you could describe more clearly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with learning Python! I made the switch from C++ about 9 years ago, and nowadays programming in C++ feels like the stone age.

In Python, every time you pass an object around, you pass *reference*, making pointer obsolete. So your code in Python would simply be:

```
class Room(MapSite):
    def __init__(self, roomNo):
        self.__roomNo = roomNo
        self.__sides = []
    def GetSide(direction):
        return self.__sides[direction]  # Presumably
    def SetSide(direction, side):
        self.__sides[direction] = side
    def Enter():
        # Your code here...
```

In Python, all functions are treated as virtual. The double underscore before a member makes it 'private'. The 'this' pointer is explicit in Python, and by convention is called 'self'.

All member variables should be defined in the constructor ('**init**' function), members defined directly in the class scope are the Python equivalent of C++ static members.

Comment: Speaking of `self`, it looks like you forgot it in your function definitions.