# Checking if a variable belongs to a class in python

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a small class which is as follows :

```
class Gender(object):
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
```

I have a parameter variable which can be only **M** or **F**.To ensure it is only that, I do the following :

```
>>> parameter = 'M'
>>> if parameter not in (Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE)
...     print "Invalid parameter"
...
Invalid parameter
>>>
```

Now I have a class which contains all the States in USA as follows:

```
class States(object):
    ALABAMA = 'AL'
    ALASKA = 'AK'
    ARIZONA = 'AZ'
    ARKANSAS = 'AR'
    CALIFORNIA = 'CA'
    COLORADO = 'CO'
    CONNECTICUT = 'CT'
    DELAWARE = 'DE'
    DISTRICTOFCOLUMBIA = 'DC'
    ....
....
```

Like the example above,my parameter now is **AL**.However, since there are 50 states in the USA,I cannot practically use the tuple with 50 variables like I used above.Is there a better way of doing this ? I did read about isinstance but it did not give me the expected results.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, take a look at [enum](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/enum.html)

Comment: you should use an [Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)

Comment: And IIRC there should be a Python 2 recipe for enums somewhere.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I'm sure there are numerous enum recipes.

Comment: @PeterWood: I was referring to the same Enum class that is in the Python 3 standard library

Comment: unfortunately..still on 2.7

Comment: There you go: [Python 3.4 Enum backported to 3.3, 3.2, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6, 2.5, and 2.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `__dict__` property which composes a class, for example:

```
In [1]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     bar = "b"
   ...:     zulu = "z"
   ...:     
In [2]: "bar"  in Foo.__dict__
Out[2]: True
```

Or as you're searching for the values use `__dict__.values()`:

```
In [3]: "b" in Foo.__dict__.values()
Out[3]: True
```

As Peter Wood points out, the [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) built-in can also be used to retrieve the `__dict__`:

```
In [12]: "b" in vars(Foo).values()
Out[12]: True
```

---

The `__dict__` property is used as a [namespace for classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) and so will return all methods, [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) and private properties on the class as well, so for robustness you might want to modify your search slightly to compensate.

In your case, you might want to use a `classmethod`,  such as:

```
class States(object):
    ALABAMA = "AL"
    FLORIDA = "FL"

    @classmethod
    def is_state(cls, to_find):
        print(vars(cls))
        states = [val for key, val in vars(cls).items()
                  if not key.startswith("__")
                  and isinstance(val, str)]
        return to_find in states

States.is_state("AL") # True
States.is_state("FL") # True
States.is_state("is_state") # False
States.is_state("__module__") # False
```

---

**Update**
This clearly answer's the OPs question, but readers may also be interested in the [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) library in Python 3, which would quite possibly be a better container for data such as this.

Comment: Be careful, this will return false positives if there is a method that matches the key as well.

Comment: No methods in my class so this should suffice..thanks

Comment: Note that this won't work with `__slots__`, a better way is to use `hasattr`, but it is different from looking up in class dictionary as it will look up everywhere in the inheritance tree.

Comment: You can access `__dict__` using `vars(Foo)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `hasattr()` would be great if OP was asking to find `bar`, but he's trying to find `"b"`

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use a dictionary? Its a lot simpler and lookups will be easier as well.

```
states = {'AL': 'Alabama', 'AK': 'Alaska' ... }
test_state = 'Foo'

if test_state not in states.keys():
    print('{} is not valid input'.format(test_state))
```

Comment: You don't even need to use `.keys()`, since `in` checks against the keys anyway. `if test_state not in states:`.

Comment: You are right - I just have a habit of using `.keys()`.

Comment: If you use the `dict` constructor you can use keyword arguments instead of creating strings. e.g. `dict(AL='Alabama', AK='Alaska')`

Comment: @Burhan..the states class is already defined for some other purpose ..it would be duplication on my part if i re-created the same content in a different format.. and hence I was specifically looking for information to access the static variable in a class

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using Enum to define both `Gender` and `States`.
[Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) if part of the standard library on `Python 3`. If you are on `Python 2` use [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), install with `pip install enum34`.

```
from enum import Enum
class States(Enum):
    ALABAMA = 'AL'
    ALASKA = 'AK'
    ARIZONA = 'AZ'
    ARKANSAS = 'AR'
    CALIFORNIA = 'CA'
    COLORADO = 'CO'
    CONNECTICUT = 'CT'
    DELAWARE = 'DE'
    DISTRICTOFCOLUMBIA = 'DC'
    ...
```

Then you can check if a variable is one of the states by

```
isinstance(variable, States)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if you can set at the beginning all your arguments it is better just to put the required arguments without default arguments. This forces the user to set the arguments. However, often you might want to set the attributes later for various reasons.

I find very handy to define a class Required that I can use as a place holder, and use a function `validate` before the object "is sent to production".

```
class Required(object):
    def __init__(self,description=None):
        self.description = description
    def __repr__(self): 
        return 'Required attribute:%s' %self.description



class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = Required(self.ID = Required("ID is mandatory, please set it using set_ID method."))
        self.context = None
        self.type = "MyClass"


    def set_ID(self,MyClass_ID):
        """
        The id property identifies this MyClass with the URL at which it is available online.
        """
        # check MyClass_ID is valid before assigning it
        # valid(ID)
        self.ID = MyClass_ID

    def validate(self):
        for i in self.__dict__.values():
            if isinstance(i, Required):
                print(i)
                # Warining or raise error

g = MyClass()
g.validate()
```