# How to do enum aggregation?

Tags: java, enums

My code consumes two libraries - LibraryA and LibraryB.

LibraryA has defined an enum :

```
public enum EnumA {
    FIRST,
    SECOND;
}
```

LibraryB has also defined an enum :

```
public enum EnumB {
    ONE,
    TWO;
}
```

How can I aggregate these two enums in my code into a single type - class or enum, say `MyAggregatedEnum` so that I can enumerate on values defined in both EnumA and EnumB.

**Edit :**
Editing to include a more concrete use case. I want to have a `Map<MyAggregatedEnum, TypeHandler>`. This map will be created statically. For each individual value, there can be a different TypeHandler. Eg. for `FIRST`, there can be a type handler - `HandlerFirst`, for `ONE`, there can be a type handler - `HandlerOne`, and so on.

Apologies for not adding this in the first draft itself.

I can't make library enums to implement some common interface.

Comment: Such that `aggregateEnumList` could contain element of either/both enum types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable enum inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650045/how-to-enable-enum-inheritance)

Comment: @jhamon, i can't make library enums to implement some common interface.

Comment: What about just creating a class with those two enums as fields?

Comment: @ernest_k yes, that's correct

Comment: So you want inheritance after all...

Comment: Wait, doesn't the old saying go "prefer composition over inheritance"!? (this was a joke) So create a holder class that can hold both `EnumA` and `EnumB` value (but not both at the same time) and work from there. Of course that class needs to function as an adapter between the enums.

Comment: If you can't make them implement a common interface, then the asnwer to your question is: you can't do that

Comment: How do you build `aggregateEnumList`? Statically in code?

Comment: @ernest_k can be a static list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work with dynamic values; but as `aggregateEnumList` is created statically, it may solve your current problem.

```
interface MyAggregatedEnum {
    String getValue();
}
```

And

```
List<MyAggregatedEnum> aggregateEnumList = 
             List.of(EnumA.FIRST::getValue, EnumB.ONE::getValue);

printValues(aggregateEnumList);
```

The `getValue` method referenced in the last snippet is not from the same API, but it provides an implementation for `MyAggregatedEnum.getValue()` (which doesn't have to be named `getValue`, by the way)

---

**EDIT**: following the edited question, I'd suggest that your solution is as simple as using the `Enum` type itself:

```
Map<Enum<?>, TypeHandler> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(EnumA.FIRST, someHandler);
myMap.put(EnumB.ONE, someOtherHandler);

...

TypeHandler firstHandler = myMap.get(EnumA.FIRST);
TypeHandler oneHandler = myMap.get(EnumB.ONE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, have edited the question to include more concrete use case.

Comment: @user2653062 That changes the question quite a bit. I've edited the answer, see the bottom section

Comment: just to clarify `TypeHandler` is not a class from standard jdk. It is a class from iBatis or some other third party library.