# How can we create an ENUM union of Other enum

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I have 3 enums in java:

```
enum A {MON,TUE,WED}

enum B{THU,FRI}

enum C{SAT,SUN}
```

I want to create enum D that should be the union of other enums. eg `D {MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN}`

What should be the best approach to achieve this.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650045/how-to-enable-enum-inheritance

Comment: Ultimately, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I am giving you an example, I want to use this while persisting value in DB. Same column is used for multiple value.

Answer (score 0):

I take it from your question that you want to do it dynamically, at runtime. This is (technically) not possible, as enums are constants. If you want to go about and introduce some hacks to make it possible, nobody will stop you. See for a starter: https://jqno.nl/post/2015/02/28/hacking-java-enums/