# How to represent enumeration classes with methods in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, enumeration, class-diagram

I have an enumeration class that has a method in the class body, how do I represent this in a UML class diagram? Is the following a valid way? (It seems reasonable but I couldn't find anyone doing this online.)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In UML an enumeration is a classifier, so it can have operations.

As strange as it feels,  the compartment with the litterals should be **below** the compartment with the operations (see UML 2.5 specifications, section 10.2.4, emphasis added by me):

> The name of the Enumeration is placed in the upper compartment with the **keyword «enumeration» above or before the name**. A list of EnumerationLiterals may be placed, one to a line, in a compartment named “literals” **below the operations compartment**. The attributes and operations compartments may be suppressed, and typically are suppressed and empty.

Comment: @qwerty_so I really like this question, forcing to check the base.  I just read that as a classifier an enumeriation could even be specialized,  in which case its litterals add to the litterals of the generalisation ^^ This evening I'll definitively go to bed with the feeling of being less dumb than yesterday ;-)

Comment: Care to know any language that supports that?

Comment: @qwerty_so I'm not aware of a language that inherits the literals, at least in Python [and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35650045) that would conflict with type theory invariants. However, languages that implement enums with a class declaration can inherit everything else with the exception of the literals.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be ok. An UML Enumeration is a DataType and that can have operations as well. See p. 165 of UML 2.5. And on p. 166:

> A compartment listing the Operations is placed below the attribute compartment.