# How do I model enums in UML so they express a key-value relation?

Tags: java, class, enums, uml, diagram

I want to represent some key-value pairs in an UML enum type. For instance, lets say we have some elements and their symbol:

```
ROAD => 'R'
CAR => 'C'
NOTHING => ' '
```

In Java, it would be something similar to the following:

```
public enum AsciiCodes { 
    ROAD  ('R'),
    CAR ('C'),
    NOTHING (' ');

    private final char code;

    private AsciiCodes(char code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

**How can I represent that in UML?**

What I have so far:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea about Java, but the above is not valid (the brackets and chars inside). Also seems like an implementation detail which should not be shown.

Comment: Hi @qwerty_so I have edited the question including a textual description of what I'm looking to represent. Thanks!

Comment: for @qwerty_so ROAD.code is 'R' etc, this is done by the compiler from the used notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In UML *ROAD, CAR* and *NOTHING* are *EnumerationLiteral* and in a class diagram they are shown in the compartment *literals* showing their name, and nothing more of them.

An enumeration being a *Datatype* may have property, however the attribute *code* from your Java cannot be supported by a property as your did because it does not concern the enumeration but the *EnumerationLiteral*.

Of course an *EnumerationLiteral* is not a property of the enumeration nor an instance of the enumeration, but an *InstanceSpecification*.

So there is nothing the standard allowing to model *code* and its value for each enumeration literal until you extend the enumeration through a stereotype to add *code* as a *StructuralFeature*, in that case the values of *code* will be specified through a *Slot*

In [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) see :

- § 10.5.3 Enumeration page 175
- § 10.5.4 EnumerationLiteral page 175 and 176
- § 9.9.9 InstanceSpecification page 140

---

**[edit]**

Alternative representation in UML inspired by the reading of [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014427/2458991)'s answer.

An other way is to completely forget the UML *EnumerationLiteral* and to model each Java enumeration literal through a dedicated instance itself available through a static read-only attribute.

*AsciiCodes* can be still an UML enumeration.

[image]

Note in your Java definition and above the value of *code* is unavailable from outside, then finally useless until an operation is added to return it as proposed in [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014427/2458991)'s answer.

By the way this is how I still implement the enumerations in the API of the *plug-out* of [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) for Java, using the stereotype *enum_pattern* specially managed by the Java code generator. I started to distribute BoUML in 2005 when the enumeration did not yet exist in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bruno! Then, your suggestion is to add a <<stereotype>> linked to the enum class? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @NilSuria if you want to really model your enum as it is defined in Java yes you have to create your own derived definition(s), and probably the simplest (and only ?)  way is to only extend *EnumerationLiteral* to add *code* so that one is not a property in your possible derived enumeration. May be you can also add an own stereotype *JavaEnumeration* for clarity to indicate the *EnumerationLiteral* are let say *JavaEnumerationLiteral* and to justify to extend the notation of each literal like `ROAD='R'` for instance ...

Comment: @NilSuria ... All of that is done at metamodel level. Of course you can also just use the new notation and stereotypes without really defining them in case you do not want to generate code from or not having the possibility to modify the generated code

Comment: @NilSuria I edited my answer to propose an other way to do

Comment: This new way fulfills perfectly my needs and seems very clear. Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add some nuance to [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65005741/3723423)'s excellent and inspiring answer.

### Can an enumeration have properties and operation in UML?

An UML enumeration is a classifier.  As such, it can perfectly have its own properties and operations, even if most of the time it only defines enum litterals  (see also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64971533/3723423)).  This is very close to Java enums.

[Java enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) provide however some syntactic sugar which allows to associate one or several constant values to each enum literal. The language allows you to define a private constructor that uses these constant values to initialize the enum object. This means that you could very well represent your enumeration in UML as follows:

[image]

### What with constant values associated with enum litterals?

Nothing in UML allows you to model the constant value(s) associated to an enum litteral.  **But nothing has to**: this is simply an implementation detail.  If you want the constants in the model, you could document them in a note  (I wouldn't go that way because it just clutters the diagram with implementation details that do not help to understand the design).

You have two choices for clarifying the initialization:

1. You define an explicit constructor with the same signature as in your code, with the advantage that it's close to your code. **But UML is not an alternative to code, isn't it?**.  The inconvenience is that it is misleadingly unclear for an UML reader: it gives the impression that these initialization parameters are free;
2. You rely on a constructor without parameters. The advantage is that it reflects the design reality: the constructor parameters are not free since Java invokes the constructor with the constant values which are directly deduced from the enum litteral.

I'd advise for 2,  because it conveys the real design intent.  Without the syntactic sugar, you'd probably write a very long `case` statement to initialize the properties with the right values depending on the enum litteral.

### What with the other Java enum features?

The UML enumeration doesn't provide anything beyond what you explicitely define.
But Java enums all specialize [`java.lang.Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), which offer operations such as `name()` or class operations such as `values()`.

If you want to convey the availability of such language-specific features,  you could define [your own stereotype](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/stereotype.html) `«Java enum»` that specializes the standard UML enumeration metamodel element.

Comment: Can you explain the names usually given to the 3 different sections in the `<<enumeration>>`. The one having enum members/literals, the other having attributes/properties, and the last with the callable methods. (Exact names depend on language, but you get the idea: in UML terms what would the 3 sections be called?)

Comment: @bad_coder the sections are called "compartment" in the UML specs (page 101). The compartments are named "attributes", "operations", "receptions" (for classifiers). For enums, the compartment is named "literals" (page 166 of UML 2.5.1 specs).