# Swift's enum with associated values in an UML class diagram

Tags: swift, enums, language-lawyer, uml, class-diagram

***This is an UML question related to Swift. It is not a Swift programming question***

Swift provides an [enum type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations/) that can be exactly like enumerations in UML: It has a value semantic, defines a set of literals, and may have operations.  The only difference is that it cannot have attributes (not even constant ones like in Java).

But Swift provides also enums with associated values. Example:

```
enum Beverage {
    case water
    case juice(String)
    case tea(flavor: String)
    case coffee (strength: Int)
    case other
}  

let b1 = Beverage.water
let b2 = Beverage.juice("Apple")
let b3 = Beverage.tea(flavor: "mint")
let b4 : Beverage = .coffee(strength: 3)
```

The associated values are provided at initialization of an instance, and are not directly accessible and can only be retrieved using pattern matching,  i.e.  in a switch statement, instead of

```
case .tea:
```

we could use:

```
case let .tea(taste):    // if the case branch is fired, taste contains the value
```

It would be tempting to use a simple enumeration and ignore the the associated values:

[image]

However, this does not capture the real nature of the swift enum, considering the UML specs:

> An EnumerationLiteral defines an element of the run-time extension of an Enumeration. Values corresponding to EnumerationLiterals are immutable and may be compared for equality. EnumerationLiterals may not change during their existence, so any attributes on an Enumeration shall be read-only.

The last sentence corresponds to the situation of a [Java enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014427/3723423) where you can associate a set of constant attributes to specific enumeration literals.  It's not fully applicable to swift's associated values,  where the associated values can change depending on the literal, and moreover the same literal may be associated to different values.

**How to best model this kind of enum in UML?**

Comment: Would a question of this nature be better suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? I honestly don't know but this doesn't seem like quite the right fit for Stack Overflow since this isn't actually a coding question. Just a thought.

Comment: Swift enums are algebraic data types, not really OOP, which UML diagrams are designed to model. Naturally, there isn't a good way to do this. See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263130/what-do-i-use-for-a-variant-in-a-uml-class-diagram).

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks. There are 6848 UML questions on StackOverflow and a number of experts to answer them. There are only 623 UML questions on StackExchange. UML is a relevant tag on SO and in scope as modeling language. See for example this Java Enum question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65002225/3723423

Comment: Rust has a similar construct.

Comment: "How to best model this kind of enum in UML?" - I believe the unfortunate answer is that UML is not designed to model this kind of algebraic data type. You could try to e.g. model the enumerators as const (no associated value) and non-const (has an associated value) static data members of a utility class along with an "active member" indicator, to highlight that they can hold a state, but this also comes with drawbacks as it does not capture that each instance of such an enum have its own state (which is the opposite of what readers of the UML diagram may perceive "static" to be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would model this as a set of datatypes specializing `Beverage`:

[image]

Swift might add some syntactic sugar, but essentially this is what it comes up to. At least as far as my limited understanding of swift enumerations goes.

Comment: There's a typo in the type of `strength`. it reads **Intteger** where it should be **Integer**

Comment: Indeed, this seems the closest match. I'd just add a generalization set `{complete, disjoint}`. Initially, I was tempted to have the base Beverage as an enum for the literals without associated values, and inherit from it for each enum with associated (read-only) attributes (i.e. the relevant literal that is added to the list+atttributes). However, this would not feel right as it creates a difference between literals that can be used in the parent's context, not to speak of the principle of least surprise when enums are inherited.  Your's much better in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly I'm a bit puzzled. As per spec an `«enumeration»` consists of  `EnumerationLiteral`s which are specializations of `InstanceSpecification`. So it should be possible to add the type of each literal.

N.B.: I tried to model that with Enterprise Architect but it only shows the name of the literal. Also their (Sparx) documentation says that it will only allow unique names. They cite just the UML passage with the *enumeration literals*.

It's however possible to construct it as another `«datatype»` which allows to have unique typed attributes. You might create a profile and stereotype that as, say, `«typed-enum»` or the like. The UML `«enumeration»` is also a specialization of `«datatype»`. So these could live side by side.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, to follow the instance specification, and play with the type.  Intuitively,  the pattern matching looks very much to the kind of things done when checking types before accessing properties.  However, I understand from "Each value of an Enumeration corresponds to one of its user-defined EnumerationLiterals.", that the type of each literal is of the corresponding enumeration type.  Let me think this through.

Comment: OP does not refer to EA and maybe doesn't even know what EA means. Therefore, I think that the abilities of EA and the Sparx documentation are irrelevant. It would be better to stick to what the UML specs say.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Well, yes. I was not suggesting the "EA-solution" but just telling what I tried. I'll make that a N.B.