# How to center allign literals compartment title in Enum class diagram?

Tags: enums, uml, class-diagram, plantuml

I want to create a class diagram of an Enum in PlantUML with the **literals** keyword centered above the third compartment according to the following quote (also referenced [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64971327)):

> [UML 2.5.1 - page 168](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF)
>
> A list of EnumerationLiterals may be placed, one to a line, in a
> compartment named “literals” below the operations compartment. The attributes and operations compartments may be
> suppressed, and typically are suppressed and empty.

Using the following PlantUML how can I get the **literals** text to be center alligned?

```
@startuml

package MyPackage {

enum MyEnum {
attrib1: str
attrib2: int
--
func1()
func2()
--
literals
ONE_LITERAL
TWO_LITERAL
}
}
@enduml
```

[image: screenshot of UML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go is described in [plantuml's documentation](https://plantuml.com/class-diagram?utm_content=cmp-true), in the section "Advanced class body", using a -- separator with title. Your example would look like:

```
@startuml

package MyPackage {

  enum MyEnum {
    attrib1: str
    attrib2: int
    --
    func1()
    func2()
    -- literals --
    ONE_LITERAL
    TWO_LITERAL
  }
}
@enduml
```

and result in:

[image]

Comment: PlantUML is somewhat limited here by not offering a simple solution to get a result exactly as shown in the UML specification.