# Why can't I subclass a subclass of Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Consider the following code:

```
from  enum import Enum

class SubclassOfEnum(Enum):
    x = 5
print(SubclassOfEnum.x)

class SubSubclassOfEnum(SubclassOfEnum):
    y = 6
print(SubSubclassOfEnum.y)
```

We get an error, `TypeError: Cannot extend enumerations`,

from: `Python36\lib\enum.py", line 436, in _get_mixins_`

Answer (score 7):

Because subclassing `Enum`s with members is [specifically disallowed](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing).

For general use-cases for `Enum` check out [When and where to use...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22586895/208880).

For [extending `Enum`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33680929/208880) (adding members to existing `Enum`s, not subclassing them)...

Comment: Thanks. The "specifically disallowed" link is broken since 3.11. It seems to have moved here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing