# Define an enum that is a subset of another enum

Tags: python, enums

My program has an `enum` called `Platform`

```
class Platform(StrEnum):
    binance = auto()
    kraken = auto()
    trading_view = auto()
```

Now I want to define another `enum` called `Exchange` that only contains platforms that are exchanges. Something like

```
class Exchange(Platform):
    binance = auto()
    kraken = auto()
```

But apparently this doesn't work because `enum`s are final, inherit another `enum` is not allowed.

I want to have functions like this:

```
def exchange_func(ex: Exchange):
    pass

def platform_func(p: Platform):
    pass
```

`Exchange` can enter both functions, but non-exchange `Platform`s can only enter the second function, assuming strict type checking is required.

If I don't define `Exchange`, just use `Platform`, then non-exchange platforms may accidentally enter the first function without showing errors.

If `Exchange` doesn't inherit `Platform`, exchanges cannot enter the second function.

As mentioned above, the main problem is that enums are final, inherit another enum is impossible. So how to solve this?

Comment: The short answer is it's not possible

Comment: Can you accept that `Exchange` is not related to `Platform` and specify `Platform or Exchange` when you need to accept either?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679930/how-to-extend-python-enum) you simply may not extend an Enum *with members*.

But to fix your functions, you don't need inheritance. Make both inherit from StrEnum and simply define the parameter as a Union.

```py
def exchange_func(ex: Exchange):
    pass

def platform_func(p: Exchange|Platform):
    pass
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid multiple unions and really want inheritance, then define a base enum class to basically categorize them.

```py
class PlatformBaseEnum(StrEnum):
    pass

class Platform(PlatformBaseEnum):
    binance = auto()
    kraken = auto()
    trading_view = auto()

class Exchange(PlatformBaseEnum):
    binance = auto()
    kraken = auto()

class News(PlatformBaseEnum):
    pass

def exchange_func(ex: Exchange):
    pass

def platform_func(p: PlatformBaseEnum):
    pass
```

If you won't have objects that are plain Platforms (non-subsets), then you can get rid of the Platform and keep only PlatformBaseEnum.

Type comparisons examples:

```py
>>> isinstance(Platform.kraken, PlatformBaseEnum)
True
>>> isinstance(Exchange.binance, Exchange)
True
```

Comment: I think `Exchange|Platform` should be in `platform_func`. But this is still not the way to go. The idea is that functions that accept `Platform` don't need to know what subsets are there. There could be another subset called `News` which only includes `Platforms` that are news outlet. I don't want to go back to every function that accept `Platform` and add `|News`. Logically, it shouldn't be this way because in this example, `News` are `Platform`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your top level enum be empty, and put the members in the subclassed enums:

```
class Platform(Enum):
    "base enum"

class Exchange(PlatformEnum):
    binance = auto()
    kraken = auto()

class Misc(PlatformEnum):
    trading_view = auto()
```