How to update/create dynamically enums in Python from a dic?
I have a custom enum, but sometimes I want to update it.
See the example below:
from enum import StrEnum

class Colors(StrEnum):
    WHITE = '#ffffff'
    BLACK = '#000000'

If I have a dict like this: {"red": "#BE3E23", "green": "#47735b"}.
How can I update this enum definition above?
My idea is to create a @classmethod function called from_dict that updates the list.
I'm not sure if I keep the StrEnum inheritance or if I move to a NamedTuple or any other better object to deal with this.

Do you want to update in between runs of your program, or while it's running?

For your use case of adding new members to an existing Enum you can use aenum (authored by @EthanFurman) with extend_enum instead. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33680929/6890912

Your idea of using a class method to update the enum definition seems fine. Here's an example of how you can achieve this using the StrEnum base class:
from enum import StrEnum
from typing import Mapping

class Colors(StrEnum):
    WHITE = '#ffffff'
    BLACK = '#000000'

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, color_dict: Mapping[str, str]):
        for color_name, hex_code in color_dict.items():
            setattr(cls, color_name.upper(), hex_code)

# Usage
color_dict = {"red": "#BE3E23", "green": "#47735b"}
Colors.from_dict(color_dict)

print(Colors.RED)  # Output: #BE3E23
print(Colors.GREEN)  # Output: #47735b
print(Colors.WHITE)  # Output: #ffffff
print(Colors.BLACK)  # Output: #000000

Edit: AS PER THE COMMENTS
In Python, Enums are designed to be immutable after they are created, so dynamically adding new members won't update the internal list of members.
To fix this, you'd have to recreate the enum dynamically, but Enums doesn't allow direct modification after definition. Here's a possible solution using metaclass to handle dynamic behavior using a custom class to mimic enum behavior, but it won't be a true Enum in the strict Python sense.
from typing import Mapping

class ColorMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, color_name):
        color_name = color_name.upper()
        if color_name in cls._colors:
            return cls._colors[color_name]
        raise AttributeError(f"{cls.__name__} has no attribute {color_name}")

class DynamicColors(metaclass=ColorMeta):
    _colors = {
        'WHITE': '#ffffff',
        'BLACK': '#000000'
    }

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, color_dict: Mapping[str, str]):
        for color_name, hex_code in color_dict.items():
            cls._colors[color_name.upper()] = hex_code

    @classmethod
    def list_colors(cls):
        return list(cls._colors.items())

# Usage
color_dict = {"red": "#BE3E23", "green": "#47735b"}
DynamicColors.from_dict(color_dict)

print(DynamicColors.RED)    # Output: #BE3E23
print(DynamicColors.GREEN)  # Output: #47735b
print(DynamicColors.WHITE)  # Output: #ffffff
print(DynamicColors.BLACK)  # Output: #000000

print(DynamicColors.list_colors()) 

# Output: [('WHITE', '#ffffff'), ('BLACK', '#000000'), ('RED', '#BE3E23'), ('GREEN', '#47735b')]


@jcfaracco: RED and GREEN are not enum members -- they won't show up in a list, are not instances of Colors, etc.

This is a horrible answer, for reasons that @EthanFurman already pointed out,
