# How to document limited values of input parameter in Docstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring, pep

I have a function that accepts only accepts some limited values for the input parameter `provider`. Specifically, it only accepts the values `provider_a`, `provider_b` and `provider_c`. What is the best way to document the possible values of this parameter in Python Docstring?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def my_func(provider: str) -> str:
    """ Sample function description goes here
    :param str provider: Provider parameter that only accepts some possible values. Possible values:
        - 'provider_a': Description of provider_a
        - 'provider_b': Description of provider_b
        - 'provider_c': Description of provider_c
    :return: provider passed as input
    :rtype: str
    """

    # DO SOMETHING

    return provider
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to docstring-only ways, your wording is pretty good; instead of the unspecific "some", I would opt to authoritatively state "the following" possible values.

But as usual, such docstrings tend to become stale fast. Instead, you might want to investigate changing the type of argument `provider` from `str` to either a lightweight Enum (see [Enums in Python: How to enforce in method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409537/2375855) for an old but relevant example), or even make your providers distinct classes (with an abstract Provider parent class).