# alternative for python Enum with duplicate values

Tags: python, enums

I like Enum a lot and I would like to do the following:

```
class Color(Enum):
    green = 0
    red = 1
    blue = 1

for color in Color:
    print(color.name)
    print(color.value)
```

As you can see, there are duplicate values in Color class. What class alternative can I use in this case that supports iterable, name, value?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/5399734 and other nice answers under that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you asking how you can have `Color.red` *and* `Color.blue` without `blue` being an alias for `red`?

If yes, you'll want to use the [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup> library and it would look something like:

```
from aenum import Enum, NoAlias

# python 3
class Color(Enum, settings=NoAlias):
    green = 0
    red = 1
    blue = 1

# python 2
class Color(Enum):
    _order_ = 'green red blue'
    _settings_ = NoAlias
    green = 0
    red = 1
    blue = 1
```

And in use:

```
for color in Color:
    print(color.name)
    print(color.value)

# green
# 0
# red
# 1
# blue
# 1
```

The downside of using `NoAlias` is by-value lookups are disabled (you can't do `Color(1)`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: @user1502776:  If you don't need the other `Enum` goodies (iterating through the class, length of the class, etc.) then you may want to use the `NamedConstant` class from `aenum`.