# Python: aenum enumeration generates error

Tags: python, enums

Today I tried an enumeration with aenum (like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/4720441):

`orientation = Enum('red', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange')`

but this generated an error in the aenum library:

> File "C:\Python\27\lib\site-packages\aenum__init__.py", line 1417,
>   in _get_mixins_
>       issubclass(base, Enum) and TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

How can I fix this?

Comment: The answer you linked to details a couple different ways -- you are trying to use an old-style way with the new `Enum`s.

Comment: I could only find the detailed documentation on `https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/aenum/src/default/aenum/doc/aenum.rst`.

Answer (score 5):

The various ways to create an Enum using call syntax are:

```
# starts at 1
SomeEnum = Enum('SomeEnum', 'member1 member2 member3')

# starts at 1
SomeEnum = Enum('SomeEnum', ['member1', 'member2', 'member3'])

# values manually assigned
SomeEnum = Enum('SomeEnum', [('member1', 3), ('member2', 4), ('member3', 5)])

# values manually assigned
SomeEnum = Enum('SomeEnum', {'member1': 6, 'member2': 7, 'member3': 8})

# starts at 9
SomeEnum = Enum('SomeEnum', 'member1 member2 member3', start=9)
```

This is the same across the [stdlib version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup>.  The [`enum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum)<sup>2</sup> package is an old-style library.

---

*The stdlib versions contain*:

### 3.4

- Enum
- IntEnum
- unique

### 3.6

- Flag
- IntFlag

*`enum34` is the same as the 3.4 stdlib.

### `aenum`

*contains the above, plus*:

- OrderedEnum - members can be compared against each other
- AutoNumberEnum - value is automatically generated
- MultiValueEnum - members can be looked up with have multiple values
- NoAliasEnum - duplicates are unique, not aliases

and various helpers to manipulate the construction of enumerations:

- skip - prevents attributes from becoming enum members (attribute stays the same)
- constant -- to prevent attributes from becoming enum members (attribute becomes a type of read-only property)
- extend_enum - add new members to an existing enumeration (useful when the Enum is built in stages)

*And extra related types*:

- NamedConstant - No enumeration fanciness, just a value with a name
- NamedTuple - similar to the stdlib `namedtuple`, but built using metaclasses instead of `eval`

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the primary author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library.

<sup>2</sup> The author of the older `enum` library also helped with the stdlib version.

Answer (score 1):

`aenum.Enum` is not constructed like this (see https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/aenum).

Instead you should be passing in a first argument containing the Enum name, and a second argument corresponding to a space separated list of enum keys you want enumerated.

E.g.

```
orientation = Enum('red', 'yellow green orange')
```

**Note on the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/4720441**

In this answer, the poster creates an `enum` function, which combines it's arguments into a `dict`, and then passes that dict to the standard Enum constructor (as the third argument).

Comment: So the example in the linked answer is wrong then? Sorry, but I'm not understanding your explanation. Like this: Enum(orientation, 'red'  'yellow' 'green' 'orange')

Comment: No, the answer there also uses a single space-delimited string for the enum values.

Comment: They add an `enum` method that takes multiple **args** and combines them into a dict, then calling the other form of the standard constructor which takes a dict as a third argument.

Comment: Alright now I kind of understand:
orientation = Enum('orientation', 'red yellow green orange')

Because strangely, after installing also the "enum" package, my initial Enum works. That confuses me.

Comment: @Creatronik: The original `enum` package is not the `Enum` that went into the stdlib, and it made different choices about construction.