# How to define an attribute from a set of possible values in Python?

Tags: python, initialization

I want to initialise a `User` class with attributes whose value is taken from a finite and immutable set of possible values (e.g., types of user, short list of countries...). What is the best approach to do that in Python?

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, type, country):
        self.type = type # Possible values: [Consumer, Producer]
        self.country = country # Possible values: [UK, USA, Japan, France]
```

It is probably obvious, but the reason for me to formally limit to this set of possible values is mainly to avoid/spot errors.

I have looked at various explanations on `list` and `Enum` in Python (e.g., [How to implement an Enum in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)), but I am not sure if it is the right way to go considering my needs. Especially, it seems – from what I have read – that `Enum` is to store a list of *constants* (`User.type` as `CONSUMER` and `PRODUCER`)... but I would like to be able to use the values directly in the output (so the uppercase seems weird). And I am not sure whether a numeric equivalent for each value (`CONSUMER=1`...) would be of much use for me.

EDIT: I should probably add that the real values in my application are in French and include thus non-ASCII characters (e.g., `États-Unis`). Going the `Enum` way seems to make it impossible to keep these characters and would mean to then "translate" the value to a "localised" value, which looks to me like a lot of trouble for a short list.

Comment: In your case, I would use List, just a simple search after that if you dont know the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all how were you thinking of making a variable out of `États-Unis` anyway ? Putting in a list? In any case, Enums are a good way to go,

To limit the choices add validation for the passed arguments `UserType` and `Country`

Secondly you can directly compare enums eg `COUNTRY.US == COUNTRY.UK #returns False` so it doesn't matter what actual values those enums have.

If you still want to retrieve the value then you can get it from `Country.US.value`

```
class Country(Enum):
    US = 'États-Unis'
    UK = 'Royaume-Uni'


class UserType(Enum):
    CONSUMER = 1
    PRODUCER = 2


class User(object):
    def __init__(self, type, country):
        if not isinstance(type, UserType):
            raise Exception
        self.type = type # Possible values: [Consumer, Producer]

        if not isinstance(country, Country):
            raise Exception
        self.country = country # Possible values: [UK, USA, Japan, France]




==> Country.UK == Country.US
==> False

==> print(Country.US.value)
==> 'États-Unis'
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I didn't understand I could assign a text value to each `Enum` key! Small clarification: I suppose I have to import the `Enum` module, or not? From `enum`, `enum34`, `aenum`?

Comment: Yep, `from enum import Enum` I think. There are other fancy kinds of enums in that module as well if you are interested, check out [Enum docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html)

Comment: please don't use type as this shadows a built-in.  your IDE should be warning you about this already.