# How can I construct an enum.Enum from a dictionary of values?

Tags: python, enums, python-3.4

I'd like to generate some types at runtime from a config file. For simplity, let's assume I already have the data loaded as a python dictionary:

```
color_values = dict(RED = 1, YELLOW = 2, GREEN = 3)
```

How can I transform this into the type (using [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html))

```
class Color(enum.Enum):
    RED = 1
    YELLOW = 2
    GREEN = 3
```

The following doesn't work

```
def make_enum(name, values):
    return type(name, (enum.Enum,), values)
```

```
>>> Color = make_enum('Color', color_values)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'
```

Comment: You should probably use an OrderedDict rather than a regular dict.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932/1959808

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis: In my defense, I remembered that question as being one pre-`enum.Enum`, which would just tell me to use it. Of course, you're right that it shows the example I needed there.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
Color = Enum('Color', color_values)
```

[Tada!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) There's a provided API for that. You can also give it an iterable of name-value pairs, or an iterable of just names (in which case the values will be auto-filled starting from 1), or a whitespace- or comma-separated string of names (which will also auto-fill values).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one super-hacky approach that seems to work:

```
def make_enum(name, values):
    _k = _v = None
    class TheEnum(enum.Enum):
        nonlocal _k, _v
        for _k, _v in values.items():
            locals()[_k] = _v
    TheEnum.__name__ = name
    return TheEnum
```

We have to use `nonlocal` there to stop `Enum` complaining about the keys `k` and `v` being duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

And another one that chooses to hit the metaclass internals instead:

```
def make_enum(name, values):
    meta = type(enum.Enum)
    bases = (enum.Enum,)
    dict = meta.__prepare__(name, bases)
    for k, v in values.items():
        dict[k] = v
    return meta(name, bases, dict)
```

Or with less `__dunder__`:

```
import types
def make_enum(name, values):
    def _update(d1, d2):
        for k, v in d2.items():
            d1[k] = v  # calls __setitem__
    return types.new_class(name, (enum.Enum,), None, lambda ns: _update(ns,values))
```