# Setting Class attributes from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a class which inherits from `Enum` and `str`. I need to define some class attributes which are defined in a .json file and is being loaded in a Python dictionary.

```
from enum import Enum

# I want to create a class like this (but assign the class attributes by reading a dict)

class Test(str, Enum):
  A = 'Alpha'
  B = 'Beta'

# Attempt to solve :

mydict = { 'A' : 'Alpha', 'B' : 'Beta' }

class Test1(str, Enum):
  for k,v in mydict.items():
    k = v

# => An Error is reported here.
```

For class instances, I can use `setattr()` but I could not find anything to set the class attributes.

Since these attributes are dynamic and could change, I do not want to hard-code the class attributes but rather read in a dictionary and set it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I construct an enum.Enum from a dictionary of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299036/how-can-i-construct-an-enum-enum-from-a-dictionary-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define your own class directly, instead use [the `Enum` functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
Test = enum.Enum("Test", mydict, type=str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setattr()` too for classes:

```
>>> class A: 
...     pass
...
>>> setattr(A, "attribute", 3)
>>> inst = A()
>>> inst.attribute
3
```

Just iterate through the dict like this:

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
     setattr(Test, k, v)
```

Comment: This will not work properly for an Enum class. It creates class attributes, but they won't become Enum objects, they'll just be whatever value you set (so you lose the benefits of using `Enum`).

Answer (score 1):

To make this *dynamic*, you can set all attributes under `__new__` magic function. An example of this is here:

```py
attr_dict ={
    'A': 'alpha',
    'B': 'beta'
}

class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in attr_dict.items():
            setattr(cls, k, v)
        return cls

x = MyClass()

x.A  # --> 'alpha'
x.B  # --> 'beta'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3**

```python
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    
    attr_dict ={
        'A': 'alpha',
        'B': 'beta'
    }
    
    my_class = MyClass(**attr_dict)
    print(my_class.__dict__)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422918/7799587) should help you.

From answer:

**Python 3**

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    exec("%s=%s" % (k,v))
```

That doesn't smell like good practice, but works.

Comment: This does not work. Not in general, if your values don't have a `str` value that reproduces them, nor will it work properly in the body of an `Enum` class, as you can't put the loop in there (it raises an error about reusing the key `k`).