# Python how to list an array and make them an Enum

Tags: python, enums

So I'm trying to achieve something like this

```
from enum import Enum

tabulate_formats = ['fancy_grid', 'fancy_outline', 'github', 'grid']

class TableFormat(str, Enum):
    for item in tabulate_formats:
        exec(f"{item} = '{item}'")
```

Though i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    class TableFormat(str, Enum):
  File "/app/src/main.py", line 26, in TableFormat
    for item in tabulate_formats:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/enum.py", line 92, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError('Attempted to reuse key: %r' % key)
TypeError: Attempted to reuse key: 'item'
```

How do I properly assign them into the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would also be acceptable, but based on [turning a `dict` into an `Enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47299205/13386979), you could do:

```
TableFormat = Enum('TableFormat', {i:i for i in tabulate_formats})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    @staticmethod
    def _generate_next_value_(name, *args):
        return name

TableFormat = StrEnum('TableFormat', tabulate_formats)
```

and

```
>>> list(TableFormat)
[<TableFormat.fancy_grid: 'fancy_grid'>, <TableFormat.fancy_outline: 'fancy_outline'>, <TableFormat.github: 'github'>, <TableFormat.grid: 'grid'>]
```